# Problem in installing robotjs npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, automation, npm-install

Can anybody help me fix this? stuck on it for 3 days tried hours and hours. I am trying to install robotjs npm package but it's giving me these errors. Tried everything I could.

PS: I already tried everything from here and other sites.

[image]

Comment: It's hard to help you if you don't tell us what you actually tried.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

i resolved a similar issue by deleting `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file, manually adding the package name in `package.json` (in your case it would be `"robotjs": "^0.6.0"`) and then, runnig
`npm i`

Comment: I tried still getting the same error. Can you tell me your node and npm version?

Comment: node v14.18.0
npm v6.14.15
also you may want to update existing packages, i remember an outdated `bcrypt` package giving me trouble